# create a model that allows the user to set parameters in algorithms

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I am trying to create a model in the graphical modeler of QGIS in which the user can configure the parameters of some algorithms, as in the Model Builder. Is it possible in QGIS?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all boxes have a label box, that if set, will display as an input when running the model. [image]

When running the model, you will see:
[image]

You can see all available input types under the `Inputs` tab
[image]